# @Url.RouteUrl returns empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, routes

has anyone any advice on this please? Mvc3 wont return me a route url from the following. I have done something very similar and it works. Neither route is complicated by any optional arguments or anything, its really all very simple. What on earth is going on?

This is in my global.asax.cs...

```
routes.Add("StateProductRoute", 
    new Route("{state}"+locationUrlLiteralPart+"/{productName}-{productType}", 
        new CustomUrlRouteHandler(CustomUrlRouteHandlerUsageType.Product))
        {
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "constraint1", new ProductConstraint() }
            } 
        });
```

...and this is in my view...

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("StateProductRoute", 
    new { state="archer", productName="hello", productType="goodbye"})" 
    class="media">
```

Comment: incidentally, if it makes any difference, the view im rendering this link on was called by a different controller to the one that will handle the StateProductRoute

Comment: What is that `locationUrlLiteralPart`?

Comment: Its literally just a string we want in the url. I have a bunch of products which are under american locations and the url might be http://www.mysite.com/colorado-holidays/thebeach-hotel

Answer (score -1):

Is there a dash missing?

```
new Route("{state}**-**"+locationUrlLiteralPart+"/{productName}-{productType}",
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: In my opinion inserting a dash after {state} should have solved the issue. It wasn't meant to be critique.